# Resources not loading when accessing my JSF XHTML

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, tomcat7, websphere-8

I deployed my application on websphere 8.5 and trying to access it in the browser. When the page is loaded the display is cluttered and when I view the pagesource, i see the following with "RES_NOT_FOUND"

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="RES_NOT_FOUND" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="RES_NOT_FOUND" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="RES_NOT_FOUND"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="RES_NOT_FOUND"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="RES_NOT_FOUND"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="RES_NOT_FOUND"></script>
<title>SUPPORT</title>
<!-- ncfb.is-asu 2012-02-13 ST02 replace  standard.stylesheets with custom -->
<link href="/TryThis/styles/mainstyle-en.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- ncfb.is-asu 2012-02-13 ST02 replace pt.styles with custom  -->
<link href="/TryThis/styles/mainstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- ncfb.is-asu 2012-02-13 ST02 replace plumtree/portal/private/css/wcidojo.css with custom -->
<link href="/TryThis/styles/wcidojo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

When I deploy the same in tomcat it is working fine. The following is the view source code snipped from tomcat.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/TryThisAppName/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces-aristo" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/TryThisAppName/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=4.0" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/TryThisAppName/javax.faces.resource/layout/layout.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=4.0" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/TryThisAppName/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=4.0"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/TryThisAppName/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery-plugins.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=4.0"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/TryThisAppName/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=4.0"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/TryThisAppName/javax.faces.resource/layout/layout.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=4.0"></script>
    <title>SUPPORT</title>
    <!-- ncfb.is-asu 2012-02-13 ST02 replace  standard.stylesheets with custom -->
    <link href="/TryThisAppName/styles/mainstyle-en.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- ncfb.is-asu 2012-02-13 ST02 replace pt.styles with custom  -->
    <link href="/TryThisAppName/styles/mainstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- ncfb.is-asu 2012-02-13 ST02 replace plumtree/portal/private/css/wcidojo.css with custom -->
    <link href="/TryThisAppName/styles/wcidojo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/TryThisAppName/styles/ncfbins-mainstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <!-- Intellect SEEC Custom Styles -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/TryThisAppName/styles/customstyle.css" />
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: show your xhtml file... And you have to give waaaaay more context e.g. what are the differences in the environments, proxy in front or not (because I see 'TryThis' vs 'TryThisAppName'), security in place or not etc...

Comment: Sorry, I changed the app name from the actual one to something like "TryThis". While doing this by mistake i typed "TryThisAppName" in one context. They both are same except one is the output when deployed on websphere and one is the output when deployed on tomcat. I found the solution to my problem. In websphere it is not able to load the primefaces theme and all from primefaces4.0.jar. So, extracted the jar and took the files theme.css and primefaces.css and placed them in my WebContent/styles folder. This fixed my problem.

Comment: Weird that this is needed…  basic jsf stuff

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem. In websphere it is not able to load the primefaces themes from primefaces4.0.jar. So, I extracted the jar and took the files theme.css and primefaces.css and placed them in my WebContent/styles folder. This fixed my problem.